# Cannot post a video to Twitter using Tweetinvi

Tags: c#, twitter, tweetinvi

I am trying to post a video to Twitter using Tweetinvi library:

```
byte[] video = DownloadBlobFromUrl(parameters.VideoUrl);
IMedia media = Upload.ChunkUploadBinary(new UploadQueryParameters { Binaries = new List<byte[]> { video }, MediaType = "video/mp4", MediaCategory = "tweet_video", MaxChunkSize = VIDEO_MB_CHUNK_SIZE * 1024 * 1024 });
publishParameters.Medias = new List<IMedia> { media };
ITweet tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet(message, publishParameters);
```

The problem is that publishing fails, unless I add, before publishing, some sort of sleep, like:

> await Task.Delay(25000);

With delay it works. Interesting is the fact that IMedia's member HasBeenUploaded is set to true. I also tried using chunk upload, but with the same result. How can I wait until video is fully uploaded to Twitter, assuming this is the issue?

Comment: Hello, I just wanted to let you know that the feature has now been implemented. This will be part of Tweetinvi version 1.2. If you want to use it right now, you can by compiling the source code. You can find an example of how to use the new feature at https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/347.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the developer of Tweetinvi.

The problem you are encountering is a problem of the Twitter UPLOAD API. The problem is that when an upload completes it takes between few milliseconds up to 1 second for their upload service to process it and make it available to you.

From there you have 2 solutions.

### Solution 1 (simplicity)

Don't specify the `MediaCategory` and use the classical `Upload` as followed:

```
var videoBinary = File.ReadAllBytes("file_path");
var videoMedia = Upload.UploadVideo(videoBinary);

Tweet.PublishTweet("test", new PublishTweetOptionalParameters()
{
    Medias = { videoMedia }
});
```

This video should be available straight away. But I have experienced times when a delay is required. Therefore I usually add a delay of 500ms for Twitter servers to be ready for the incoming Tweet.

### Solution 2 (amplify_video)

`amplify_video` is a more robust solution as it is the solution provided by Twitter to solve the delay problem.

```
var videoBinary = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\linvi\Pictures\mov_bbb.mp4");
var videoMedia = Upload.UploadVideo(videoBinary, "video/mp4", "amplify_video");

var isProcessed = videoMedia.UploadedMediaInfo.ProcessingInfo.State == "succeeded";
var timeToWait = videoMedia.UploadedMediaInfo.ProcessingInfo.CheckAfterInMilliseconds;

while (!isProcessed)
{
    Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);

    // The second parameter (false) informs Tweetinvi that you are manually awaiting the media to be ready
    var mediaStatus = Upload.GetMediaStatus(videoMedia, false);
    isProcessed = mediaStatus.ProcessingInfo.State == "succeeded";
    timeToWait = mediaStatus.ProcessingInfo.CheckAfterInMilliseconds;
}
```

I realize that this is complicated but few people uses `amplify_video`.
In the next release I will add a new method that will do all this logic automatically for you.

If you want to be informed when this feature is released you can find the work item here : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/347.

I will also provide a new enum for `ProcessingInfo.State` (https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/issues/348).

I hope this answer helps you.
Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, not so elegant, but it works. You have to set the media category to **amplify_video**. For anyone else with this issue:

```
byte[] video = DownloadBlobFromUrl(parameters.VideoUrl);
IMedia media = Upload.ChunkUploadBinary(new UploadQueryParameters { Binaries = new List<byte[]> { video }, MediaType = "video/mp4", MediaCategory = "amplify_video", MaxChunkSize = VIDEO_MB_CHUNK_SIZE * 1024 * 1024 });
publishParameters.Medias = new List<IMedia> { media };
IUploadedMediaInfo status = Upload.GetMediaStatus(media);

int numberOfTries = 1;
while (status.ProcessingInfo.State != "succeeded" && numberOfTries < VIDEO_UPLOAD_TRY_COUNT)
{
   numberOfTries++;
   await Task.Delay(VIDEO_UPLOAD_WAIT_SECONDS * 1000);
   status = Upload.GetMediaStatus(media);

 }

if (status.ProcessingInfo.State == "succeeded")
{
     tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet(message, publishParameters);
     return tweet.IdStr;
 }
```